How to keep track of backup table to be used for restoration?
In my project, for a particular operation I am creating backup of 1 table, which the operation is using. So every time a new backup table is created. For restoration, I have to restore from one of the tables of the backup whichever end-user selects.
So my question here how do create the backup table ? Or Keep track of the backup tables ?
Limitation is the backup <table_name> I have to know before any restoration or checking if the table exist or not. So if I generate the name with time based suffix then the name I will not be able to find properly.

What about creating a table, adding a record to it, and use that primary key as table name with a prefix? That way you'd be able to store additional information besides the identifier.

Do not add lots of conflicting tags for different RDBMS (as they all have different syntaxes and functionality). Only tag the one that you are using.

@Caramiriel This I have thought of till now. I am checking here if there are other ways or not. Also for backup and restore I have to interact with 2 tables, that would a be an extra overhead right ?

@MT0 I am using all three databases postgresql, oracle and mysql. So need a generic solution rather than a specific database.

Don't have multiple tables; have one table.
If you have the table:
CREATE TABLE main (
  a INT,
  b DATE,
  c VARCHAR(50)
);

and you want to create a backup for a specific user at a specific date:
CREATE TABLE main__backup(
  username    VARCHAR(50),
  backup_date TIMESTAMP,
  a INT,
  b DATE,
  c VARCHAR(50)
);

Then if you want to "backup" the table that is just copying the main table:
INSERT INTO main_backup (username, backup_date, a, b, c)
SELECT current_user, current_timestamp, a, b, c FROM main;

If you want to "restore" the table that is just deleting the main table and copying the backup table. For example, to restore to something saved 5 minutes ago:
DELETE FROM main;

INSERT INTO main (a, b, c)
SELECT a, b, c
FROM   main_backup
WHERE  username    = current_user
AND    backup_date = current_timestamp - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE;


I got your point but creating a table as the original one and restoring from the backed up table is that not more efficient ?
May be inserting into another table and always querying will work. But is that efficient.
Mostly I want to store the state of the table without any changes for backup.

@StrawHat04 It is probably going to be less efficient to create lots of "backup" tables. If you are dynamically creating tables then: you need to use dynamic SQL; you need to create the new table each time you need a backup; you need somewhere to store what the dynamic table name is (probably another table); you need to delete tables afterwards; etc. Using dynamic tables just gets to be a complicated mess. But if you really want to do it then profile both solutions and compare.

Also, creating lots of "backup" tables is going to probably require database specific syntax as I doubt that you can write dynamic SQL code that runs on Oracle, MySQL and PostgreSQL (I'm pretty certain that what you write for Oracle will not work for MySQL and PostgreSQL and fairly certain that the PostgreSQL code won't work for the other two either).

I will try to compare these 2 but creating and deleting table will come into play but I don't to create as the first original table creation as I can just use the CREATE TABLE AS statement to create backup table from the original.
Though DDL I have to use every time here instead of the DML.
Also I will restrict the number of backup tables. Will not allow more than a certain number. Thanks for the idea though.
